# Get multiple documents where document identifiers are XXX

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know it's possible to fetch a multiple documents where a specific field meet a certain condition. I don't know if Firestore yet has support for it and if they even will, but is it possible to fetch multiple documents where document id meets a certain condition?

For instance, I'm trying to fetch all documents under my `Users` collection where all documents identifiers are equals to my `userIDs: [String]`.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the documents within your `Users` collection are unique, you cannot get "all documents identifiers that are equals to" because in that collection will always exist a single document with that particular document id. In order to solve this, you can use:

```
let docRef = db.collection("Users").document("yourParticularUserId")
```

And then make a `getDocument()` call and then simply check if the that document exist. That's it!

Comment: Yeah that's how i'm doing at the moment. But by doing so I have to do multiple calls to fetch all the users I want. So I was just checking if it's possible to reduce to just one simply call. But I guess I have to live with this?

Comment: That's the way it works. If you want to fetch multiple users, create a new property in each user object and add as a value an identifier. Then simply query your `Users` collection using `usersRef.whereField("newProperty", isEqualTo: "yourIdentifier")`, right?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, but I'm using the Firestores own unique identifier, which will be set after the first call. So then I have to make another call to set the fieldValue as it's own document ID. But thanks!